# How to stop a button from toggling within div tag using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, button, toggle

I have a link which triggers div tag to toggle. The problem is that I don't want my button(which is within the div), to toggle. How do I stop it from toggling?

This is my html code:-

```
<a href="#" id="uploadVideoLink" class="menuLink"> Upload Videos </a>
<div id="uploadVideos" class="menu">
  <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Upload" id="btn" />
</div>
```

This is my jQuery code:-

```
$(document).ready(
  function upload(){$("#uploadVideoLink").click(
     function uploadTog(){$("#uploadVideos").toggle();}     
  );}   
);
```

Comment: Well, the button is **inside** the div. If you don't want to hide it when the div is hidden, you have to take it out.

Comment: Actually, the purpose of this jQuery is to behave like tabs. When I click on the link, the div appears. Within div, I don't want my button to toggle when I click it. Only div should toggle.

Comment: Maybe he wants to toggle everything inside the div but the button

Comment: I'm a "she". Yes that's exactly what I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean that you don't want to hide the button that's not possible i think as long as the button is inside the div becuase `toggle()` assign `display: none;` to the div thus hiding everything inside it

One thing you could do is this one (this would toggle all elements inside the div but not the button):

```
<a href="#" id="uploadVideoLink" class="menuLink"> Upload Videos </a>
<div id="uploadVideos" class="menu">
    <div>sometext</div>
    <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Upload" id="btn" />
    <div>sometext</div>
</div>

$(document).ready(

function upload() {
    $("#uploadVideoLink").click(

    function uploadTog() {
        $("#uploadVideos *:not(#btn)").toggle();
    });
});
```

fiddle 
http://jsfiddle.net/K5NL4/

Comment: Ahw sorry,.. I'm new here. Ok i'll accept. I found where it is. Thanks by the way :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to get it outside the `<div>` you can't hide an element without all the elements inside of him. It's just the way DOM is.

Comment: If I put the button outside div then my button will be shown. I only want it to display when the div is toggle. However, I don't want my button to function like a toggle.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you will need to move the button outside the div. With a little styling you should be able to get the interface to look right.

Either position the toggled-on DIV on top of the outside button, and place another identical button inside the DIV on top of the original button. Or position the toggled-on DIV adjacent to/just below the button, and just create a border that makes it seem like the button is now 'part' of the toggled DIV.